# Counting ways of placing coins on a grid

Tags: algorithm

the problem requires us to find out the number of ways of placing R coins on a N*M grid such that each row  and column has at least one coin. Constraints given are N , M < 200 , R < N*M. I initially thought of backtracking, but i was made to realise that it would never finish in time . Can someone guide me to another solution? (DP , closed form formula.) any pointers would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

According to [OEIS sequence A055602](http://oeis.org/A055602) one possible solution to this is:

```
Let a(m, n, r) = Sum_{i=0..m} (-1)^i*binomial(m, i)*binomial((m-i)*n, r)

Answer = Sum_{i=0..N} (-1)^i*binomial(N, i)*a(M, N-i, R)
```

You will need to evaluate N+1 different values for a.

Assuming you have precomputed binomial coefficients, each evaluation of a is O(M) so the total complexity is O(NM).

### Interpretation

This formula can be derived using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) twice.

a(m,n,r) is the number of ways of putting r coins on a grid of size m*n such that every one of the m columns is occupied, but not all the rows are necessarily occupied.

Inclusion-Exclusion turns this into the correct answer.  (The idea is that we get our first estimate from a(M,N,R).  This overestimates the correct answer because not all rows are occupied so we subtract cases a(M,N-1,R) where we only occupy N-1 rows.  This then underestimates so we need to correct again...)

Similarly we can compute a(m,n,r) by considering b(m,n,r) which is the number of ways of placing r coins on a grid where we don't care about rows or columns being occupied.  This can be derived simply from the number of ways of choosing r places in a grid size m*n , i.e. binomial(m*n,r).  We use IE to turn this into the function a(m,n,r) where we know that all columns are occupied.

If you want to allow different conditions on the number of coins on each square, then you can just change b(m,n,r) to the appropriate counting function.

Comment: You might want to explain how you're using binary matrices to solve a problem where the solution doesn't necessarily involve only 0 or 1 coins in each entry.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are getting at.  We need to clarify how many coins can be placed on a single square in the grid.  I have assumed a maximum of 1 because that is what the code in the previous question assumed.  I'll add a request for clarification to the question.

Comment: If it turns out that the entries *are* binary, then I won't bother trying to post an answer; this is cleaner than anything I was going to come up with.

Comment: Wait ... I think that this solves the #4 part of my answer, combine them and I believe you should be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough, but if you begin by working out how many ways you can have at least one coin on each row and column (call them reserve coins). The answer will be the product of #1 `(n! / r! (n - r)!) *`, where #2 `n = N*M - NUMBER_OF_RESERVE_COINS` and #3 `r = (R - NUMBER_OF_RESERVE_COINS)` for #4 each arrangement of reserving one coin on each row/column.

#4 is where the trickier stuff takes place.  For N*M where N!=M, `abs(N-M)` tells you how many reserve coins will be on a single rows/columns. I'm having trouble on identifying the correct way of proceeding to the next step, mainly due to lack of time (though I can return to this on the weekend), but I hope I have provided you with useful information, and if what I have said is correct that you will be able to complete the process.